# How can I trigger a value change event in a subvi, that has a reference to the possible changing value?

Tags: event-handling, onchange, labview

I have a subvi that receives two references to paths as input.
The subvi does its thing and changes the value of the second path, based on the first one. (it adds a folder of the user's choice) One can consider the first path reference to truly be an input and the second one to be an output. (think C: passing a pointer to something that should be modified by the function instead of returning the value)

Say I plug in a root directory, the vi writes a sub directory to the second path reference.

```
"/" -> subvi -> "/subdirectory/"
```

This works fine.

Now I want to chain two of these subvis together, so that the user can choose two layers of a folder structure, like so:

```
"/" -> subvi1 -> "/subdirectory/" -> subvi2 -> "/subdirectory/subsubdirectory/"
```

Just to be clear: this is the same subvi, used twice in the same main vi in subpanels.

The chain vis do not work as intended. **Each subvi registers a value change event of the first path reference.** My motivation to do this was to notify any subsequent instance of the subvi that the value of its root path changed.

Changes made in subvi1 should be reflected in subvi2 so that subvi2 operates on the path chosen in subvi1. **The change event never fires.** And the changes in subvi1 are not reflected.

Is this because I have path **references** as inputs? Adding a value change event to them would mean that the reference has to change in order to fire it, which is not the case. If so, **how do I add a change event to what the reference is referencing instead of the reference itself?**

Am I overcomplicating this by using a reference? **Should I just use a path instead of a reference to a path?**

Please take a look at the following image, it shows how the two subvis are created and shoved into the subpanels.

[image: code]

And some more information, I hope this helps.

Each subvi simply adds a case for a change event of the first path reference it receives.

> Use Value (Signalling) when setting your value by reference. This change of value will generate a value change event.
>   And writes its results via value(signalling) to the second reference.
>   I have the suspicion that this is where the problem is, because it changes the value of what's referenced, not the reference itself.

The value change event is never executed.

> LabVIEW doesn't have reference to paths. I assume you mean a reference to a path control (which also tracks with the value change event you're talking about).

ok, I am misusing the terminology. My apologies for any confusion. Yes, I mean a reference to a path control.

> If you do need to pass things as messages (for instance, if you have parallel processes), I would suggest using other mechanisms, like user events, rather than value change events. VC events work, but they're designed for UI use. Using them programmatically can make your code convoluted.

I do need this in parallel, because I have 2 subvis. How is this convoluted? I pass a reference to what is about to change and that's it. [If the information should go the other way, from main, to subvi, the suggested solution from national instruments is also to pass a reference as can be seen in this tutorial.](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/A882E27D1D7A949386256E0D0066B91A)

> you're only registering for the event after it already happened

I'm not sure how this can be, because both subvi persist in main. I can click them repeatedly and this should repeatedly fire change events.

Comment: It might make it a little clearer by including a snippet of the code you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LabVIEW doesn't have reference to paths. I assume you mean a reference to a path control (which also tracks with the value change event you're talking about). I would definitely say that using the path directly is better. Take advantage of the fact that LV does not need the ugly hack of passing a reference to return multiple values from a function. By value tends to work much better in dataflow if you can do it. If you do need to pass things as messages (for instance, if you have parallel processes), I would suggest using other mechanisms, like user events, rather than value change events. VC events work, but they're designed for UI use. Using them programmatically can make your code convoluted.

That said, without code it's impossible to say exactly what your issue is, but my best guess based on your description is that you're only registering for the event after it already happened, so it's not added to the queue of the second VI, but that's just a guess, because your description isn't very clear.

In general, a better place for these questions is the NI forums (and you'll definitely want to include code if this doesn't help you and you post there).

As a last point, you're not registering for a value change of the reference. Wiring the reference to the register node will always give you the options for registering for the events of the object the reference points to (a path control, in this case).

Comment: thank you, I much prefer SO over any other forum. I edited my question to provide more information. Could you please elaborate on what that "register node" is that you mention? Is it the register node that can be seen in the tutorial that I linked to? thanks

Comment: The register node does indeed do the trick, why is registering dynamically different from doing it "statically", as I did before? Could please elaborate on the difference if possible? thanks

Comment: SO is great for certain things. Asking these types of LV questions is not one of them. Here are some reasons:
1. There aren't many LV users here.
2. You can't comment without it either saving your edits or eating the line breaks.
3. You can't attach actual code.
4. This type of thing often requires a discussion, which is explicitly what SO is not designed to do.
5. Editing the existing content is great for certain things, but pretty bad when you're trying to solve a problem of this type.

In short, I would suggest using the NI forums and attaching actual code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. For static registration the event structure has to be in the same VI as the control. Any other registration (using the register for events node) is dynamic.

Again, if you have further questions, I would suggest posting to the NI forums and posting actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Value (Signalling)](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvprop/ctrl_value_signaling/) when setting your value by reference. This change of value will generate a value change event.

However, overall, it seems like a strange architecture to me, though without seeing the code and requirements it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you have a race condition in your code - you launch the VIs in parallel, so there's no telling what order they would run in, and it's possible that one will update before the other gets to register.

That's assuming it's even two separate VIs as your text suggests. Looking at your image I would have guessed it was the same VI and in that case the VIs can't run in parallel because you're using a static reference, so even if the VI is reentrant you would get the same instance. If you just took the VI and create a copy of it with a different name I would suggest you read on reentrant VIs and how to launch them dynamically.

Comment: It is the same subvi. It is executed in parallel. They are running all the time, so there is no race condition. They are re-entrant and it works. I have two apparently independent instances of the subvi. From my results I'd have to say this answer is wrong.

Comment: Correct. I was sure this doesn't work, but a quick test seems to indicate that they do run in parallel, even with preallocated reentrancy. I'm not sure why I had in mind that you have to create a dynamic reference. Anyway, you're still likely to have the race condition I talked about and without actual code it's hard to tell.